# what's the size and type for facebook profile picture?

Tags: facebook, profile, image

I tried to upload a 512x512 PNG image for the profile picture of a page that we own on Facebook, but it failed w/o showing the image after I uploaded the image file. Could there be something wrong with the PNG image or the size of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

180 x 540 in jpg
is what I use for mine
There is a tutorial with sizes etc here :
http://www.clear-river.com/weblog/comments/making_the_most_of_your_facebook_page_profile_picture/
I think 512PX wide is way too wide, as the logo is only a thin strip.